# How to establish a connection to an EV charger via OCPP 1.6 from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket

```
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import express from "express";

const app = express();

class CSM {
  constructor() {}

  get_current_time() {
    return new Date().toISOString();
  }

  init() {
    this.port = 8090;

    this.ws = new WebSocketServer({ port: this.port });

    this.ws.on("listening", () => {
      console.log(`Listen on port ${this.port}`);
    });

    this.ws.on("connection", (ws) => {
      ws.on("message", (data) => {
        console.log("%s", data);

        try {
          const [MessageTypeId, UniqueId, Action, Payload] = JSON.parse(
            data.toString()
          );

          switch (Action) {
            case "BootNotification":
              ws.send([
                3,
                uuidv4(),
                Action,
                {
                  status: "Accepted",
                  currentTime: this.get_current_time(),
                  interval: 14400,
                },
              ]);

              ws.send([
                2,
                uuidv4(),
                "RemoteStartTransaction",
                {
                  connectorId: 1,
                  idTag: "738961FE",
                },
              ]);

              break;
            case "Heartbeat":
              ws.send([
                3,
                uuidv4(),
                Action,
                { currentTime: this.get_current_time() },
              ]);
              break;
            case "StatusNotification":
              ws.send([3, uuidv4(), Action, {}]);
              break;
            default:
              console.log("%", data);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error: ", error);
        }
      });

      ws.on("error", (error) => {
        console.log(error);

        ws.send([
          4,
          uuidv4(),
          "BootNotification",
          {
            status: "Accepted",
            currentTime: this.get_current_time(),
            interval: 14400,
          },
        ]);

      });
    });
  }
}

const csm = new CSM();

csm.init();
```

**Error message:**

[2,"170870499378","BootNotification",{"chargePointModel":"c8","chargePointSerialNumber":"SN1120620007","chargePointVendor":"crev","firmwareVersion":"V00.49.15"}]
RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid payload length 1
at Receiver.getInfo (C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\ocpp\node_modules.pnpm\ws@8.16.0\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:303:28)
at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\ocpp\node_modules.pnpm\ws@8.16.0\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:159:16)
at Receiver._write (C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\ocpp\node_modules.pnpm\ws@8.16.0\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:98:10)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:399:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:340:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:344:10)
at Socket.socketOnData (C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\ocpp\node_modules.pnpm\ws@8.16.0\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1303:35)
at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9) {
code: 'WS_ERR_INVALID_CONTROL_PAYLOAD_LENGTH',
[Symbol(status-code)]: 1002

I'm trying to establish communication with an EV charger via OCPP.16 but an error occurs when trying to establish the connection. I'm not sure how to reset or regenerate it so that the connection can be established.